# cl.exe is not being found in path variable but works after having been added programatically

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, environment-variables, pycuda

I am trying to get started with CUDA programming with pyCUDA and am unable to get the program to recognize 'cl.exe' even though I have already added its path to my PATH environment variable.

I am following [this tutorial](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/tutorial.html) using this code:

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy

a = numpy.random.randn(4,4)

a = a.astype(numpy.float32)

a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)

cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu, a)

mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void doublify(float *a)
  {
    int idx = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y*4;
    a[idx] *= 2;
  }
  """)
```

When I try to execute the above code, I get the following error

> nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH

Which is odd because I have already added its path to the PATH env variable

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64

The path itself is indeed correct because when I add the path programatically, the CUDA code is compiled and the script executes. I.e. when I prepend the above code with the following code, it works:

```
import os

if (os.system("cl.exe")):
    print("cl.exe not found the first check")
    os.environ['PATH'] += ';'+r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64"
if (os.system("cl.exe")):
    raise RuntimeError("cl.exe still not found, path probably incorrect")
```

So my question is what could be the possible reasons for why the cl.exe is not found even though I indeed added its correct path to the PATH env variable?

Comment: one possible reason:  you added it to the PATH variable but did not restart your python session or command shell to pick up the change.

Comment: yup that definitely is it...... thanks